# Slicing dataframe by date returned nothing in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have dataframe `df`:

```
         id         timestamp           data group_id   date
56729   56970   2020-02-01 01:22:52.717 21.0    1   2020-02-01
57135   57376   2020-02-01 14:11:22.633 38.0    3   2020-02-01
57136   57377   2020-02-01 14:11:22.733 39.0    3   2020-02-01
57137   57378   2020-02-01 14:11:23.637 39.0    3   2020-02-01
57138   57379   2020-02-01 14:11:23.737 40.0    3   2020-02-01
```

and code:

```
df = df[df['data'] >0]
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01 00:00:00')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-01 00:00:00')

df = df.loc[(df['timestamp'] > start_date) & (df['timestamp'] < end_date)]

df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'])
df = df[df['date'] == '2020-02-01']
```

Column `date` was created based on `datetime` so that I can group the `df` by `date` later on. But the code returned nothing when I sliced `df` by a certain date, say `2020-02-01`, where there is data for that day. The output looks lie this:

```
    id  timestamp   data    group_id    date
```

which is only the column names. What is wrong?

Comment: Comparing a string with a datetime object does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `df[date]` columns contains `datetime` like values, not `string`, so those will not be equal to `'2020-02-01'`, you can either do:

```
>>> df[df['date'] == pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01')]
```

Or,

```
>>> df[df['date'].astype(str) == '2020-02-01']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `df['date']` date object type data, while you are comparing it with string on line `df = df[df['date'] == '2020-02-01']`. Have a look on below solution:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'timestamp': ['2020-02-01 01:22:52.717', '2020-02-01 01:24:52.717', '2020-02-02 01:22:52.717',
                     '2020-02-03 01:22:52.717']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
print(df['timestamp'])


start_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01 00:00:00')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-01 00:00:00')

df = df.loc[(df['timestamp'] > start_date) & (df['timestamp'] < end_date)]

df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
print(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'])
df = df[df['date'] == pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01')]

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
0   2020-02-01 01:22:52.717
1   2020-02-01 01:24:52.717
2   2020-02-02 01:22:52.717
3   2020-02-03 01:22:52.717
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
0    2020-02-01
1    2020-02-01
2    2020-02-02
3    2020-02-03
Name: date, dtype: object
                timestamp        date
0 2020-02-01 01:22:52.717  2020-02-01
1 2020-02-01 01:24:52.717  2020-02-01
```